# Transforming multiple columns into a list of nested dictionaries in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks in the following way

```
category    sub_cat     vitals      value
HR          EKG         HR_EKG      136
SPO2        SPO2        SpO2_1      86
HR          PPG         HR_PPG_1    135
SPO2        PI          PI_1        4.25
HR          PPG         HR_PULSED   135
NIBP        SBP         NIBPS       73
NIBP        DBP         NIBPD       25
NIBP        MBP         NIBPM       53
```

and I'd like to group by category and sub_cat columns and convert it into a list of nested dictionaries something like this

```
[{
    "HR":
    {
        "EKG":
        {
            "HR_EKG": 136
        },
        "PPG":
        {
            "HR_PPG_1": 135,
            "HR_PULSED": 135
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "NIBP":
    {
        "SBP":
        {
            "NIBPS": 73
        },
        "DBP":
        {
            "NIBPD": 25
        },
        "MBP":
        {
            "NIBPM": 53
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "SPO2":
    {
        "SPO2":
        {
            "SpO2_1": 86
        },
        "PI":
        {
            "PI_1": 4.25
        }
    }
}]
```

I was able to either group by (category, vitals, and values), or (subcategory, vitals, and values) but was not able to group by all 4 columns. This is what I tried and works for 3 columns

```
df = df.groupby(['sub_cat']).apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['vitals'], x['value'])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A series of nested `groupby` + `apply` + `to_dict` calls will do it:

```
dct = df.groupby('category').apply(
    lambda category: category.groupby('sub_cat').apply(
        lambda sub_cat: sub_cat.set_index('vitals')['value'].to_dict()
    ).to_dict()
).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(dct, indent=4))
{
    "HR": {
        "EKG": {
            "HR_EKG": 136.0
        },
        "PPG": {
            "HR_PPG_1": 135.0,
            "HR_PULSED": 135.0
        }
    },
    "NIBP": {
        "DBP": {
            "NIBPD": 25.0
        },
        "MBP": {
            "NIBPM": 53.0
        },
        "SBP": {
            "NIBPS": 73.0
        }
    },
    "SPO2": {
        "PI": {
            "PI_1": 4.25
        },
        "SPO2": {
            "SpO2_1": 86.0
        }
    }
}
```